# More efficient way to sum values in multiple arrays

Tags: python

Hello is there better way to sum multiple arrays? Because what I did is nested loop and i am not fan of this solution.

```
a = [1,2,8,7,4], [6,7,2,1,6], [7,5,1,2,3]
sum = []
total = 0

for i in a:
    for j in i: 
        total = total + j
        sum.append(total)

print(sum[-1])
```

expected output: 62

Comment: *Use* `sum` instead of shadowing it.

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/16668765 you can try `sum(sum(a, []))` oh it's super inefficient but fun

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sum` inside the comprehension (generator expression) for each sub-lists in the list, then pass it to the `sum` builtin again.

```py
>>> sum(sum(i) for i in a)
62
```

Or, map each sub-list to the `sum`, and pass it to `sum`

```py
>>> sum(map(sum, a))
62
```

Comment: Yeah, map also does the same; however, I'm fond of the comprehension.

Comment: Yes, it's comprehension but not the list comprehension, it's generator expression, and people also refer to it as generator comprehension.